# Fitting no linear R (where I am going wrong?)

Tags: r, curve-fitting

```
espfio<- c( 0.05,   0.06,   0.07,   0.08,   0.09,   0.10,   0.11,   0.12,   0.13,   0.14,   0.15,   0.16,   0.17,   0.18,   0.19,   0.20)

sensibilidade <-c(  1.51,   1.49,   1.47,   1.43,   1.35,   1.19,   0.96,   0.85,   0.65,   0.64,   0.58,   0.56,   0.52,   0.52,   0.49,   0.50)

plot(espfio,sensibilidade)

B1 = 1
B2 = 1
B3 = 1

fit1 <- nls(sensibilidade ~ B1*(exp(-exp(-B1-B2*espfio))), start=list(B1=B1,B2=B2,B3=B3))
summary(fit1)
```

> Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates

Comment: Have you tried any other starting values ...

Comment: this looks like a typo. You have B1, B2, B3 in your starting parameters, but only B1 and B2 in your formula: did you mean `B1*(exp(-exp(-B2-B3*espfio)))` ???  Having B3 missing from the formula will mean that the derivative with respect to B3 is always zero ... Also, check out `?SSgompertz`, which is I think equivalent to your model ...

Answer (score 5):

Even with the correction noted in the comments it fails with a singular gradient so to get it to converge let us fix B3 at 1 giving the `fit2` fit to the two parameter model and then use the result of this fit as input to a second fit -- this one to a three parameter model `fit3` (red line on plot).  Although these models converge the result does not look like a very good fit on the plot (see red line).    Better would be to add a fourth parameter as in the `fit4` model below (see green line on plot) -- note that `fit4` uses the `"plinear"` algorithm which does not require starting values for the linear parameters.  The  linear parameters are named `.lin1` and `.lin2` and correspond to a new parameter and to the `B3` parameter in the `fit3` model respectively.  We could also consider a Weibull model as implemented in R's `SSweibull` as in the `fitw` model below (see blue line on plot) although visually `fit4` (green) looks better and has a superior residual sum of squares.

```
# fit model in question - red
B1 <- B2 <- B3 <- 1
fo <- sensibilidade ~ B3 * exp(-exp(-B1-B2*espfio))
fit2 <- nls(fo, start = list(B1 = B1, B2 = B2)) # 2 parameter model
fit3 <- nls(fo, start = c(coef(fit2), B3 = 1)) # 3 parameter model

plot(sensibilidade ~ espfio)
lines(fitted(fit3) ~ espfio, col = "red") # show fit3 in red

# fit 4 parameter Weibull - show in blue
fitw <- nls(sensibilidade ~ SSweibull(espfio, Asym, Drop, lrc, pwr))
lines(fitted(fitw) ~ espfio, col = "blue")

# 4 parameter version of fit3 - show in green
fit4 <- nls(sensibilidade ~ cbind(1, exp(-exp(-B1-B2*espfio))), alg = "plinear", 
    start = coef(fit2))
lines(fitted(fit4) ~ espfio, col = "green")

legend("topright",, c("fit3", "fitw", "fit4"), col = c("red", "blue", "green"), lty = 1)

# residual sum of squares of each model - smaller is better
sapply(list(fit2 = fit2, fit3 = fit3, fitw = fitw, fit4 = fit4), deviance)
       fit2        fit3        fitw        fit4 
1.393555807 0.152539371 0.012960157 0.006555876
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I suspect the problem with the Gompertz fit here is that it's 3-parameter (i.e. asymptotes are 0 and A) while the Weibull is 4-parameter (left and right asymptote could both be non-zero)

Comment: Yes, good point. I have added a 4 parameter version of the model in the question (fit4 / green line).

Comment: I would +1 again but I already voted ...